# Can I get US sales taxes refunded for electronics purchased while on vacation?

Tags: united-states, taxes, shopping

I'm visiting the US for vacations (specifically Manhattan) and wanted to buy a digital camera.

The guy at the shop told me that I can get back what I pay in NYC taxes for that camera if I present the ticket at the airport, when I'll be returning home. And that this is not applicable to clothes but it does to electronic stuff.

Is any of this true?

Comment: I am not certain, but we may also need to know your country of residence.

Comment: Weird, I was told that no tax refunds are allowed when I purchased my iPad (NYC, last fall). Also check if you need to show some documents signed by the retailer. I learnt this the hard way on my UK trip at the airport. I gave away £86 just like that. :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit, _refund_ was the word I was looking for.

Comment: Related, but dealing with New York State sales tax, not NYC municipal sales tax: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/travelled-to-new-york-state-bought-something-can-i-get-sales-tax-refund-back

Comment: New York has a sales & use tax. Use tax, while rarely enforced to the extreme, is particularly noxious. If you buy a disposable camera anywhere to take a picture in NY, the State wants use tax paid.

Comment: @duffbeer703 Are you sure about use tax? In most states, use tax is collected from _residents_ on items they purchase out of state and import into the state for use, and not on visitors who buy a camera, disposable or otherwise, to take a picture in the state. The visitor _does_ need to pay the sales tax and it is nonrefundable. If the camera is delivered _out-of-state_, then NY doesn't charge sales tax on the purchase (or at least it didn't in 1995!) but the purchase was liable for use tax in the state of delivery, though, as you say, enforcement is not always very vigorous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, sales tax is not refundable to anyone. What the merchant described to you may sound familiar because that's what happens in countries that charge VAT. But he bluntly **lied**. Neither the state nor the city of New York refund the sales taxes.

Comment: +1 This sounds about right to me (see original comment above). The apple store told me the same thing.

Comment: I wonder how many people they take advantage of every day :(

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed, but you won't find locals in these stores, only tourists. That might give you a clue as to the quality and reputation.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you bought the phone in a [duty free shop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty-free_shop), probably not, and even then you may have to pay duties when you return. TripAdvisor [sums this up nicely](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g191-c1484/United-States%3aSales.Tax.html):

> Sales taxes are imposed on merchandise that you take with you from the
>   shop. **Unlike VAT schemes, there is no "export" price or system for a
>   refund of the tax if you take the merchandise with you outside of the
>   U.S.** However, sales taxes will not be imposed on merchandise that you
>   have shipped back to your home in another country, or in some cases,
>   back to your home or hotel in another U.S. state.

In the United States, sales taxes are [imposed at the state, county, and/or city level](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/373/~/how-to-obtain-a-refund-of-sales-tax-paid-while-visiting-the-united-states), so obtaining a refund could entail dealing with quite a few different jurisdictions. Unless you purchased the phone in a jurisdiction that doesn't levy sales tax (some states don't), you're required to pay it.

There *are* some states that offer international visitors an exemption from sales taxes at certain registered merchants, e.g. [Texas](http://www.taxfreetexas.com/requirements.html) and [Louisiana](http://www.louisianataxfree.com/refund_instructions.html), but unless you showed the merchant your documentation at the time of purchase and obtained a refund voucher then, I don't think you can claim a refund.