# Can I get sales tax refunded after shipping my vessel abroad from Florida?

Tags: sales-tax, florida

I recently bought a vessel and I want to ship it overseas from Florida USA.
I was told that I will be able to get my sales tax refunded if I make copies of it's title and bill of lading, then send the documents to tax collectors.
Is this a valid information? I cannot find much about it online.

Note: I live in Florida

Comment: It would be sales tax with the state of Florida. The IRS only handles Federal taxes.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, do you know the process by any chance? Do I need to go to tax collector with documents? I am also not sure which docs to prepare

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get US sales taxes refunded for electronics purchased while on vacation?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/can-i-get-us-sales-taxes-refunded-for-electronics-purchased-while-on-vacation)

Comment: The dup'ed question is about New York, but it is generally the same answer for all the States. There's no general "sales tax exemption" for tourists, and in a very few cases where there is - you need to have all the documents at the time of purchase.

Comment: @littleadv thank you for the reply! If you tried to say here that I just cannot refund sales tax, then that is alright (and I live in Florida, I am not a visitor). I am not trying to be greedy here, but it is always good if you can get money back from the US goverment. I am asking the question because I heard it from other people. I am curious if it is true.  If it is true, then I want to know the process, I cannot find much online.

Comment: @Danny711 if you live in Florida then what's your claim? And again - it's not "the US government", sales taxes are collected by States and local municipalities. The US government has nothing to do with them.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. IRS handles federal taxes, sales tax is a state tax; the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I have updated my question. Is there a way to get sales tax back once you ship a good out of states? If there is then how do I do it? That is my main question.

Comment: @littleadv, I am not a tourist. I got it, US gov has nothing to do with it. Is it a common to refund sales taxes on the purchase that was shipped overseas? I posted this question because I heard that people can do it and in a hope that someone who knows how this works will explain the process.

Comment: @Danny711 no, it's not common. It's not a thing at all. I don't know what you heard, you'll have to ask people you heard it from to explain.

Comment: When you say "shipped overseas",  to what purpose? If you are a FL resident and will still be using your boat, there's no reason to expect you should receive a refund. If you are *selling* the boat as a wholesaler, then you would likely have been eligible to not pay sales tax in the first place.

Comment: @chepner, my friend, who lives overseas, sent me money to buy him a vessel. I will send it to the shipping company that will send it overseas. My friend told me that I can get sales tax refunded. He does not live in Florida, so his claim is not 100% legit. I want to know if what he says is true. If it is true, then  how to do it.

Comment: If your friend needs you to buy the boat for him (why?), let him reimburse you for the tax. Consider it a convenience fee. Is this an *actual* friend, or someone you met online a month ago?

Comment: @chepner I dont know what you are alluding at. I gave him full qoute that includes shipping, sales tax etc. I dont pay a cent. He said if I get tax back I can keep it. If you dont have the answer then just leave it alone. I seems you are making fun of me. Not cool...

Comment: I'm not making fun of you, but there are *so* many questions on this site where someone asks about a clear scam or money laundering scheme while assisting a "friend" with some financial transaction. Just wanted to make sure you were not similar being taken advantage of.

Comment: @chepner, I am sorry for then. Thakn you for you worry!

Comment: @Danny711 so you're basically acting as an intermediary for a foreigner buyer? Do you take ownership of the boat yourself? Or are you just the one showing up with a suitcase of cash at the dealership, but the friend's name is on the title? Exporting is different than resident purchase.

Comment: @littleadv, I wanted to get it from the factory, but only dealers can do it... I need to buy it from the dealership. Then ship it out to him. It is on my name, then I need to figure if In eed to mention his name on the titile, so he can re-register it where he lives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have had a similar question, with a differnt sate, in the past. Remeber sales and use taxes are run by the states.

I went looking an found: [Sales and Use Tax on Boats: Information for Owners and Purchasers](https://floridarevenue.com/Forms_library/current/gt800005.pdf)

> **What is Taxable?**
> **Sales and Use Tax**
>
> All boats sold, delivered, used, or
> stored in Florida are subject to Florida’s sales and use tax, plus any
> applicable discretionary sales surtax, unless exempt. Florida boat
> dealers and brokers are required to collect tax from the purchaser at
> the time of sale or delivery.

So what exemptions are there?

> **Specific Exemptions**
> **Boats Sold to Nonresidents**
>
> A boat sold by or
> through a registered dealer or broker to a purchaser who is a
> nonresident of Florida at the time of taking delivery of the boat in
> Florida is exempt. This exemption applies to the sale of a boat,
> including any accessories, but does not apply to the sale of a boat
> trailer

There are rules regarding how quickly the boat has to leave the state, if the purchaser is a non-resident.

But if you are resident, you are out of luck.

> This exemption does not apply to a Florida resident, an entity in
> which the controlling person is a Florida resident, or a corporation
> in which any officers or directors are Florida residents

Comment: I cant upvote it for you,but this is a useful answer. Thank you!